# Infragistics WebGrid vs. Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I have been using the [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/Default.aspx) UltraWebGrids for a few years now in multiple products, but have reached a crossroads with them.  I have been looking into the [Telerik](http://telerik.com) products and they appear to perform better than the Infragistics grids in the demos.

**The following are the things I'm looking to know.**
1. Which would you use and why.
2. Which grid performs better.
3. Which product is quicker to implement.
4. Which product is easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 so you can find out for yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go Telerik. And if you get 80 more rep at the time of writing this you might get a free license.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/thanks-to-both-stackoverflow-and-telerik-for-the-awesome-promotion

I use Telerik at work. I use to use Infragistics a while back. Telerik is way easier to use and seems fast enough for me. I never had performance issues with them.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly Telerik!
I work with their controls for years - and also with some competitor suites (what shall I do if the customer....)

Anyhow telerik was the best I ever used.

And it's so easy to use this thing - I blogged about it.
http://manni-at.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!82CF2A6C0D0C6F3C!224.entry

Last not least you will see the same editing cappabilities with their Silverlight suite sooner or later. This means there is such an Editor for Silverlight - but (at the moment) it has not all features.

Answer (score 3):

Once I started using Teleriks Suite, I have NEVER looked anywhere else.  It has everything I need hands down.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has already pointed out Telerik are the way to go - with one caveat - make sure you take the support option too. Their documentation is really bad, the forums are slow (and responses take ages) but their support guys are excellent. Send them a repro and they'll send you back a working version within a day.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple comments of how bad Telerik's documentation. If you think Telerik is bad, you will most likely go crazy trying to find anything in Infragistics.

This question was asked a while ago but Telerik has came out with KendoUI now. Depending on what you need, I HIGHLY recommend that suite more than any.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post.

http://www.jerryodom.com/technology/telerik-mvc-infragistics-mvc-on-a-1-day-comparison

Telerik is easier to Infragistics.

And Infragistics MVC control does not "Menu" control yet.